# Find the Sum of All real solutions to the equation $X^4+(2-X)^4=34$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Help with this problem please

> Find the Sum of All real solutions to the equation
>
> $$X^4+(2-X)^4=34$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:   the equation is invariant under the transformation $\,X \mapsto 2-X\,$, which suggests the substitution $X=y+1\,$, leaving the biquadratic $y^4 + 6 y^2 - 16 = (y^2-2)(y^2+8)$ to work out.

Comment: How did you get the substitution $X=y+1$ ?

Comment: @user373141 $\;X^4+(X-2)^4=\big((X-1)+1\big)^4+\big((X-1)-1\big)^4\,$, so introducing the new variable $\,X-1=y\,$ will see the odd powers in $\,y\,$ cancel out.

Comment: @user373141 Otherwise put, the LHS is invariant under $\,X \mapsto 2-X\,$ so it has an axis of symmetry at $\,X=2-X \iff X=1\,$. Offsetting the independent variable so that $\,X=1\,$ becomes the new origin will give an even function in $\,y=X-1\,$ and, since it is a polynomial, that means only even powers of $\,y\,$.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of the exercice is to find the sum of the (real) roots of the polynomial $P(X) = X^4 + (2-X)^4 - 34$.

The [Vieta's fromulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) relate the coefficients of a polynomial to sums and products of its roots.

If you expand your polynomial you will get:

$P(X) = 2X^4-8X^3+24X^2-32X-18$. If we call $S$ the sum of real roots we will have:
 $S = -\frac{-8}{2} = 4$

Comment: But only *two* of the roots are real in this case, so Vieta's formulas can't help here to find their sum.

Comment: You are right. I forgot that...